# "Nuget pack" seems to ignore BasePath parameter

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package

I am trying to create a NuGet package using our TFS 2013 build. I basically followed [THIS](http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2014/02/24/nuget-like-a-pro-the-msbuild-way/) steps and locally everything works fine.
But our build does not use the default output directories and that seems to crash the `nuget pack` command.
On my local machine everything is builded into `SOLUTION/PROJECT/bin/Release`, but the TFS Build uses `BUILD/Sources/SOLUTION/PROJECT` for the sources and `BUILD/Binaries/Release` as its output directory. Running the build I get the following log/error:

> BuildPackage:
>    "D:\BUILD\Sources\SOLUTION\.nuget\NuGet.exe" pack "D:\BUILD\Sources\SOLUTION\PROJECT\PROJECT.csproj" -Properties "Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU" -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory "D:\BUILD\Binaries\Release" -symbols -NoPackageAnalysis -BasePath "D:\BUILD\Binaries\Release"
>     Attempting to build package from 'PROJECT.csproj'.
>
> D:\BUILD\Sources\SOLUTION\.nuget\NuGet.targets(133,5): error : Unable to find 'D:\BUILD\Sources\SOLUTION\PROJECT\bin\Release\PROJECT.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.

I then added the `-BasePath "$(TargetDir)"` to the `BuildCommand` in `NuGet.targets`, but still no change:

```
<BuildCommand>$(NuGetCommand) pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties "Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)" $(NonInteractiveSwitch) -OutputDirectory "$(PackageOutputDir)" -symbols -NoPackageAnalysis -BasePath "$(TargetDir)"</BuildCommand>
```

**How can I tell NuGet to load the correct files using TFS?**

*UPDATE:*
I found a workaround: If I set the build output path of the project to the same "relative path" as used by our TFS build it works...
But that can't be the solution, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same exact problem as you in my own TFS builds. The problem is that when `NuGet pack` is invoked with a `csproj` file, it literally evaluates the `csproj` as a MSBUILD file and the default `OutDir` MSBUILD property is set to `{ProjectDir}\bin\{ConfigurationName}`.

But with TFS builds, the output directory is usually set to a staging location such as `BUILD/Binaries/Release` in your case.

What you are missing, is this `OutDir` property to `NuGet pack`, here is an example that should work for you:

`<BuildCommand>$(NuGetCommand) pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties "Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutDir=$(OutDir)" $(NonInteractiveSwitch) -OutputDirectory "$(PackageOutputDir)" -symbols -NoPackageAnalysis -BasePath "$(TargetDir)"</BuildCommand>`

With this additional `OutDir` property, NuGet should be able to find your newly built binaries and add them to the package.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this "project" is "on hold" here now, as it is working with the workaround at the moment and with TFS 2015 such operations (NuGet pack and push) are supported natively, so we are not spending any more time on "doing it manually" ;-)...

Comment: from http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1486: OutDir must ends with backslash \ (on Windows). And when the OutDir contains spaces it must be quoted, but there is another bug/feature in command line parsing - backslash before quote must be doubled. Full workaround is -Properties OutDir="$(OutDir.Trim('\\'))\\"

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to add a blank space after $(TargetDir): <BuildCommand>$(NuGetCommand) pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties "Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutDir=$(OutDir.Trim('\\'))\\" $(NonInteractiveSwitch) -OutputDirectory "$(PackageOutputDir)" -symbols -BasePath "$(TargetDir) "</BuildCommand>

Answer (score -1):

Setting OutDir or other path related parameters might not be enough. For example, it will not work for the case if your `.nuspec` is including files by relative path, it will fail to find them.

What worked for us is specifying the `-Build` option for `nuget pack`. From [the docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#pack-command-options):

> Build :   Determines if the project should be built before building the package.

It will try first to build the project (with default parameters + supplied properties) and will correctly find output files with all included files.

Comment: Not useful: using `-Build` causes nuget.exe to create new output files instead of finding the ones created by the TFS build agent. Building more than once is never a good idea, but more importantly: NuGet.exe won't pass the same MSBuild arguments as the TFS build agent.